# Jar File Not getting created with ant script

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to execute an ant script which will compile, create the jar & execute.
I am getting "Build successful" message. But the jar file is not getting created.

My ant file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="TestAnt" basedir="." default="compile">
    <description>simple example build file</description>
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="output" location="bin"/>
    <property name="dist" location="."/>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac includeantruntime="false"  destdir="${output}">
            <src path="${src}"/>
    <!-- <classpath refid="java"/> -->
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/Test.jar" basedir="${output}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Test"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run">
        <java jar="${dist}/Test.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line `<project name="TestAnt" basedir="." default="compile">` to `<project name="TestAnt" basedir="." default="jar">`. This will both compile and create the jar - since compile target is a dependent on the jar task.

Answer (score 1):

How do you call you ant script? If you just run ant like that:

```
ant
```

It will only compiles your files, as this is the default target. To build the jar, you have to call the `jar` target:

```
ant jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are calling the correct target? Because your default target is `compile`, not `jar`, so if you supply no target, no jar file will be created.